# Convert every character entered in textfield need to be coneverted into uppercase in wicket page

Tags: transform, converters, uppercase, wicket-1.5

I have a requirement, program should convert every character entered into wicket textfield should be transformed to upper case. and when we get the value from model, it should be an uppercase String.

**UpperCaseBehavior.java**

```
import org.apache.wicket.Component;
import org.apache.wicket.behavior.AttributeAppender;
import org.apache.wicket.model.Model;

public class UpperCaseBehavior extends AttributeAppender {'
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public UpperCaseBehavior() {
        super("style", new Model<String>("text-transform: uppercase"), ";");
    }

    @Override
    public void bind(Component component) {
        super.bind(component);
        component.add(new AttributeAppender("onkeyup", new Model<String>(
                "this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()"), ";"));
    }
}

**adding upper case behaviour to textfield**<br/>
TextField<String> comp= new TextField<String>("chitMasterId",
                new PropertyModel<String>(this, "id"));
comp.add(new UpperCaseBehavior());
```

Above code is working fine when I enter characters sequentially. Assume ‘|’ as cursor.
Ex: ABCDEF|
When I bring the curser to middle (somewhere but not to the end) of the String 
Ex: ABC|DEF
And as soon as I enter character the character is getting converted into upper case 
And curser is going to the end of the string. 
Ex: ABCGDEF|
I am unable to change characters at the middle of the string sequentially.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I have updated the question. Please suggest me something.

Comment: Do you have to do this by JavaScript and in onkeyup? Wouldn't it be sufficient to convert them to uppercase onSubmit?